# Navigating to another page in php:

Tags: php, url

I use that function to navigate to another page:

```
define('WEB_ROOT', '/');
function redirect($location) 
{
    header('Location: ' . WEB_ROOT . $location);
    die();
}
```

And I deliver it the following address:

```
   $lastPageTransfer=$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."?threadID=".$threadID."&page=".$pager->MaxPage;
    redirect($lastPageTransfer);
```

It doesnt matter what the get variables are.. what I get is this:

```
http://politicalforum/Thread/thread.php%20%20%20?threadID=23&page=4
```

when the navigation completes and I get an error from google saying it cant find the page.

But I do get it to work, if I put the  $lastPageTransfer into an attribute of a link
`<a href=...`:

```
http://localhost/PoliticalForum/Thread/thread.php%20%20%20%20?page=2&threadID=23
```

Another thing to ask.. why are the %20 generated adn how can I prevent it?!?

UPDATE:

I get this:

```
http://localhost/localhost//PoliticalForum/Thread/thread.php?threadID=23&page=5
```

when I do this:

```
$lastPageTransfer=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."?threadID=".$threadID."&page=".$pager->MaxPage;
```

Comment: Can you provide us the content of `WEB_ROOT . $location`?

Answer (score 0):

%20 is an encoded whitespace. You avoid it by not having whitespaces in your links.

Regarding the link I'll take a shot on that you haven't supplied a host name:

```
http://politicalforum/Thread/thread.php%20%20%20?threadID=23&page=4
      ^
```

which could be:

```
http://www.example.com/politicalforum/Thread/thread.php%20%20%20?threadID=23&page=4
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Were `www.example.com` should be your host name. In the case were you use it in a link it's included `localhost` as hostname automagically. The behavior comes from that when using `<a href..` you don't need to have full paths.

From the [manual](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> HTTP/1.1 **requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location:** including
>   the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept
>   relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
>   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a
>   relative one yourself

Comment: I get this: http://localhost/localhost//PoliticalForum/Thread/thread.php?threadID=23&page=5     when I do this: $lastPageTransfer=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."?threadID=".$threadID."&page=".$pager->MaxPage; see update

Comment: Is that from the browser or from an echo?

Answer (score -1):

This is called URL encoding/escaping. To fix that, you need to [unescape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) the URL.